# How to embed Selenium Firefox browser into PyQt4 frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, pyqt4

I hope this question isn't too far-fetched. I'm good with Selenium and I've been working with PyQt4 recently. I want to use them both together with a program I'm currently working on and it'd work out a lot more smoothly if I could embed the controllable browser into a Qt4 frame or widget. Can this be done? And if so, how?

It doesn't have to be done with Selenium, I just want to be able to control the browser or at least show a webpage in a Qt widget or frame.

Comment: See this https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver and https://www.topcoder.com/challenge-details/30055911/?type=develop

Comment: This might work. I found something else that could work as well right as you commented though. Currently checking out both. Thanks

Comment: Do post your findings here

Comment: One minute. I may have found the solution and I'm currently working on actually applying it. I'll post my code once it's finished and working

Comment: Update: I got it working as it's own QMainWindow, I just need to set it to work in a QFrame instead.

Comment: Just posted the answer
I tested it as well and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research into methods other people have used, I figured it out.
The code I used came from a "very simple browser" module I obtained from [here](https://codescience.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/very-simple-web-browser-on-pyqt4-and-webkit/)

I modified the code to be more customizable for my future self.
Here's my modified version of the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, size=[800,600], frame=None, centralWidget=None, default_url='https://www.google.com', backButton=True, forwardButton=True, topBar=True):
        """
            Initialize the browser GUI and connect the events
        """

        self.showBackButton = backButton
        self.showForwardButton = forwardButton
        self.showTopBar = topBar

        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(size[0],size[1])
        if (centralWidget == None):
            self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        else:
            self.centralwidget = centralWidget

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mainLayout.setMargin(1)

        if (frame == None):
            self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        else:
            self.frame = frame

        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        if (self.showTopBar):
            self.tb_url = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        if (self.showBackButton):
            self.bt_back = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        if (self.showForwardButton):
            self.bt_ahead = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)

        if (self.showBackButton):
            self.bt_back.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon().fromTheme("go-previous"))
        if (self.showForwardButton):
            self.bt_ahead.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon().fromTheme("go-next"))

        if (self.showBackButton):
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.bt_back)
        if (self.showForwardButton):
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.bt_ahead)
        if (self.showTopBar):
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tb_url)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.html = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.html)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)  ---  Not needed when embedding into a frame

        if (self.showTopBar):
            self.connect(self.tb_url, QtCore.SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.browse)
        if (self.showBackButton):
            self.connect(self.bt_back, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.html.back)
        if (self.showForwardButton):
            self.connect(self.bt_ahead, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.html.forward)
        self.connect(self.html, QtCore.SIGNAL("urlChanged(const QUrl)"), self.url_changed)

        self.default_url = default_url
        if (self.showTopBar):
            self.tb_url.setText(self.default_url)
        self.open(self.default_url)

    def browse(self):
        """
            Make a web browse on a specific url and show the page on the
            Webview widget.
        """

        if (self.showTopBar):
            url = self.tb_url.text() if self.tb_url.text() else self.default_url
            self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
            self.html.show()
        else:
            pass

    def url_changed(self, url):
        """
            Triggered when the url is changed
        """
        if (self.showTopBar):
            self.tb_url.setText(url.toString())
        else:
            pass

    def open(self, url):
        self.html.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.html.show()
```

It could use some work at the moment, but I've tested it out and it's doing exactly what I need it to do. I tested it out with the following chunk of code that runs when the script is executed

```
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    window.resize(800,600)
    myFrame = QtGui.QFrame(window)
    myFrame.resize(200,200)
    myFrame.move(10,10)

    main = Browser(centralWidget=myFrame, default_url='https://www.google.com/', forwardButton=False, backButton=False, topBar=False)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Like I said, it could use work, but it does exactly what I needed it to do. Now I can embed it into a frame (with the size of my choosing) to use within another application.

Regarding my modifications: I made it possible to keep/remove the back button, forward button and top bar (for the URL). But the webbrowser is still controllable using the "open" function.

And if you wanted to open another webpage, it's as simple as the following

```
main.open('https://your.webpage.here.com')
```